# Whose buttocks are these?

Tags: charles-stross, laundry-files

In Charlie Stross' *[Overtime](https://www.tor.com/stories/2009/12/overtime)*, Bob Howard finds himself stuck in the office at Christmas, having 'volunteered' as Night Duty Officer. He begins to settle in for a boring couple of nights, when he finds a strange photocopy:

> One of the copiers has a print job stacked facedown in the output tray.
>
> (...)
>
> I flip the first sheet over to look for the header page, and do a double take. *Buttocks!* Pretty damned hairy ones, at that. *So* someone *was enjoying the party.*
>
> The next page features more buttocks, and they’re a lot less male, judging by the well-filled stockings and other identifying characteristics. I shake my head. I’m beginning to work out a response—I’m going to pin them on one of the staff notice boards, with an anonymous appeal for folks to wipe down the copier glass after each use—when I get to the third sheet.
>
> Whoever sat on the copier lid *that* time didn’t have buttocks, hairy or otherwise—or any other mammalian features for that matter. What I’m holding looks to be a photocopy of the business end of a giant cockroach.
>
> Maybe I’m not alone after all. . . .

Now later on, a certain character is implied to be not quite human:

> Kringle crosses his arms affrontedly. At least, I think they’re arms—they’re skinny, and there are too many elbows, and now I notice them I realize he’s got two pairs.

But was the copy his? If so, why? If not, whose was it?

Comment: It occurs to me it is indeed Kringle's posterior, left as a clue for the Night Duty Officer to find. From Kringle's temporal perspective, he needed to maneuver the NDO into the right position expecting him to be killed by the Filler of Stockings.

Comment: He did say he put it there to alert Bob. Whether it was his own or he got it somewhere else is not important.

Comment: After so promising a title, seeing the question really disappointed me :)

Comment: "What buttocks are these, that sat to rest, on the photocopier are peeking. - to thectune of Greensleeves

Comment: Well @Gallifreyan, I'll leave it to you about the identities of the two human pairs before these, but I highly doubt there is an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It was Kringle.** He came back in time (or forward in time, depending on your perspective) and created the photocopies in order to make Bob aware that he was in danger. Note the reference to (insectoid) double elbows earlier in the piece as well as this exchange:

> The spectral shade in its ragged robe bobs its head—or whatever it has
> in place of a head. “The Christmas incursion—” I glance at the cold
> furnace again, then at my watch “—would have killed you. But without
> Forecasting Ops to warn us about it, it’d happen anyway, wouldn’t it?”
> Three minutes. **“So you had to maneuver someone into position to deal
> with it even though you don’t exist.”**
>
> I remember sitting through a bizarre and interminable lecture at the
> Christmas party. But who else remembers sitting through it? Andy
> doesn’t remember Kringle’s talk. And I bet that **aside from my own
> memories, and a weirdly smudged photocopy—emergent outcome of some
> distorted electron orbitals on a samarium-coated cylinder—there’s no
> evidence that the ghost of Christmases
> rendered-fictional-by-temporal-paradox ever visited the Laundry on a
> wet and miserable night.**

Stross also (semi-)confirmed this theory in a recent tweet.

> [image: A tweet and its reply, transcribed below]
>
> **Answerguesser401:** @cstross - I'm confused. In Overtime, who did the (photocopied) insectoid buttocks belong to?
>
> **Charlie Stross:** @Answerguesser40 re read it. Hint: temporal paradoxes happen.
> 10:16 AM - 7 Feb 2015